# How do i display the text "</Hello>" on my website?

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on my first website which is gonna be a portfolio for my future projects. The question is probably silly but what i want to do is to greet the people on to my site with the text `</Hello>` since I'm in programming, but when i write this in my paragraph element the editor thinks that i want to create a new element...

```
<p id = "hello">        
    </Hello>
</p>
```

Comment: take a look at this.. http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: You'll need to use the character entity code - https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `&lt;` to replace the `<` would do the trick, there are some special characters that you have to display it in this way.

check out more on http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score -3):

you can use this for showing html on your page

```
<p id = "hello">        
   <xmp> </Hello> </xmp>
</p>
```

working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/maky/uw6kmkq4/)

Comment: The `<xmp>` tag is *deprecated*.  Do not use it.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp